# CAcert Research Lab Overlapping Sums Test fail

Tags: algorithm, random

I wrote a random number generator, and test the result with [CAcert research lab](http://www.cacert.at/cgi-bin/rngresults) and here the result:

[image: test result]

> o Overlapping sums test
>   • Integers are floated to get a sequence
>   U(1),U(2),... of uniform [0,1) variables. Then overlapping
>   sums,S(1)=U(1)+...+U(100), S2=U(2)+...+U(101),... are formed.The S's
>   are virtually normal with a certain covariance matrix. A linear
>   transformation of the S's converts them to a sequence of independent
>   standard normals, which are converted to uniform variables for a
>   KSTEST. The p-values from ten KSTESTs are given still another KSTEST.

Does anybody know about the solution or what is the most problem that fail the `Overlapping sums test` ?

Comment: What is your algorithm?

Comment: @NiklasB. I am using different functions in my algorithm. AES + some Gf(2^16) multiplication, some xor and etc